# How to iterate over selected_objects collection and ignore the active_object

Tags: python

I want to do something with each of the *selected_objects* as long as the object is not the *active_object*.

To put this into perspective here is a small (non working) operator that represents part of my code. I want to specify the  `x` location for each of the *selected_objects* by copying the `x` location from the active_object.

So I need to loop over the *selected_objects* and drop the object that happens to be the *active_object*.

```
#AlignXObject
class AlignXObject(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "align.x_object"
    bl_label = "Align X Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self,context):

        sel_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects
        act_obj = bpy.context.active_object

        act_obj_location = bpy.data.object[act_obj].location[0]

        for obj in sel_obj:
            if obj != act_obj:
                bpy.data.object[???].location[0] = act_obj_location
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `bpy.context.selected_objects` is a collection of references to all selected objects, and will include the *active* object.
- `bpy.context.active_object` is a single reference.

There are a number of ways to get a list of selected objects that don't include the active object. The following give a list called `selected` of selected objects except the active object.

**list Comprehension**

```
ctx = bpy.context
active = ctx.active_object
selected = [o for o in ctx.selected_objects if not (o == active)]
# selected = [o for o in ctx.selected_objects if o != active]

# or even a generator expression.
# selected = (o for o in ctx.selected_objects if o != active)
```

or

**set() boolean**

```
ctx = bpy.context
active = ctx.active_object
selection = ctx.selected_objects
selected = set(selection).difference(set([active]))
```

then the code would be like this, see the complexity is taken out of the loop and dealt with earlier - like a pre-filter.

```
for obj in selected:
    obj.location[0] = act_obj_location
```

To use your own code it would look like this, there's nothing wrong with this approach.

```
for obj in sel_obj:
    if obj != act_obj:
        obj.location[0] = act_obj_location
```

Avoiding letting your code get too nested can help readability - it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: And I just thought I formulated the questions well ... but you are right!

Comment: You'll get the hang of it Claas. promise.